# What is the difference between JSONB and JSONL?

Tags: json, jsonb

I was going through some past questions for inserting json data into a postgresql table and learnt about JSONB and JSONL. I couldn't understand the difference between the both as both looks same as a list of json data i.e.

```
[{"a":"b","c":"d"},{"a1":"b1","c1":"d1"}]
```